# SQLAlchemy: Merging table data with foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm running into issues when trying to update rows that use a foreign key as part of their primary key. Here's a simplified case:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo_table'
    foo_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('bar_table.bar_id'), primary_key=True)
    foo_data = Column(String(255))

    bar = relationship('Bar', backref='foos', foreign_keys=[bar_id])

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar_table'
    bar_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

First I'll create an entry for the `foo_table`:

```
f = Foo()
f.foo_id = 1
f.foo_data = 'Foo Data'
```

Now I'll create a row in the `bar_table` and associate the two:

```
b = Bar()
f.bar = b
```

Great! We'll add `f` to our session and commit:

```
session.add(f)
session.commit()
```

Now pretend we run into another instance of `Foo` with the same `foo_id` and related to the same `Bar`, but with some new data:

```
f = Foo()
f.foo_id = 1
f.foo_data = 'NEW Foo Data'
f.bar = b
```

That's fine! This happens all the time, right? I'll just update the information in the `foo_table` using `session.merge()` instead of `session.add()`:

```
session.merge(f)
```

But this is not fine! The code breaks and I get the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1689, in merge
    self._autoflush()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1282, in _autoflush
    self.flush()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2004, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2122, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2086, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 373, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 532, in execute
    uow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 149, in save_obj
    base_mapper, states, uowtransaction
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 301, in _organize_states_for_save
    state_str(existing)))
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: New instance <Foo at 0x10a804590> with identity key (<class 'test.Foo'>, (1, 1)) conflicts with persistent instance <Foo at 0x1097a30d0>
```

Does anyone know why this update fails?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a really good answer for this... I've ended up querying to determine whether or not I'm working with new data.

So any time I create a new instance of `Foo`:

```
old_foo = session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.id == id).all()
if old_foo:
    foo = old_foo[0]
else:
    foo = Foo()
```

This doesn't seem ideal, but I've yet to find another solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

Merging an object that is already present in the session will give the error you saw.

Relationships have a `cascade='save-update, merge'` setting enabled by default:

- `save-update` will add any related objects to the session when calling `session.add(object)`.
- `merge` which will include any related objects when merging with `session.merge(object)`.

This is described in more detail in [SQLAlchemy's documentation on `session.merge()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_state_management.html#merge-tips).