# SQLAlchemy Unique Relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am creating a couple of SQLAlchemy tables like this:

```py
association_table = Table(
    'association', Base.metadata,
    Column('snp_id', Integer, ForeignKey('snps.id')),
    Column('pheno_id', Integer, ForeignKey('phenos.id'))
)

class SNP(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'snps'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    phenotypes = relationship("Pheno",
                            secondary=association_table,
                            back_populates="snps")

    def __init__(self, name, phenos):
        self.name = name
        self.phenos = [Pheno(i) for i in line[13].split(';')]

class Pheno(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'phenos'

    id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True,
                    index=True)
    category = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    snps     = relationship("SNP",
                            secondary=association_table,
                            back_populates="phenotypes")

    def __init__(self, category):
        self.category = category
```

This is a many-to-many relationship, millions of SNPs will have the same pheno categories, and they can each have multiple pheno categories. I want the pheno categories to be unique, but I want to have a full association between the two tables. I am sure this is simple, but I am struggling with a good way to do it, other than tracking all of the Pheno objects in a dictionary and linking them manually that way.

To build this database I am just iterating over a tab delimited file that is many millions of lines long, so I want to do this the most efficient way possible.

Obviously, just trying to run something like the above code fails with this error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: pheno.category [SQL: 'INSERT INTO pheno (category) VALUES (?)'] [parameters: ('Arthritis',)]`

Comment: Sorry, I dont entirey understand the domain and terminology, but are you sure what youre looking for is 'unique' and not 'enum' ( http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) ?

Comment: This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751205/prevent-duplicate-table-entries-in-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy?rq=1

Comment: @SijoPGeorge Thanks, that is the same problem I had, and the solution is interesting. For my usage, I create the entire database just once, so I ended up tracking all existing rows using a dictionary. The solution you referenced would not work in my case, as I use the statement language for insertion, not the ORM... because I have 9 million rows and the ORM would take days instead of an hour.

Comment: @creativeChips Thanks, but an enum would require that I know all of the possible entries already. There are thousands, so I do not want to even try to do that. What I need is an elegant way to insert into the table if the row does not already exist, otherwise just link to the existing record. I had hoped there would be a nice SQL way to do this, but there apparently isn't. The workaround SijoPGeorge suggested works, but it is still just a workaround. My solution of tracking entries with a dictionary works too, but it also lacks elegance.